# Discord.py | Как упомянуть бота

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Я бы хотел узнать как я могу сделать так, чтобы вместо использования префикса я мог просто упомянуть бота написать команду и это работало так же как и с префиксом, только без него. Как сделано у других ботов.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68034636/how-do-i-set-bot-mention-as-a-bot-prefix-discord-py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите в качестве префикса `commands.when_mentioned_or("!")`

```
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"))
```